# Drawing the histogram using Python

Tags: python, histogram

I have a matrix A(20374, 1).
I would like to draw histogram(DVH) using this data.

My code is as below.

```
edge_A = np.linespace(0, max(A), 1000)
x_A = np.linespace(0.5*max(A)/1000, max(A), 1000)
n_A = np.histogram(A, bins=edge_A)
y_A = 1 - np.cumsum(n_A / len(A), axis=0)
plt.figure()
plt.plot(x_A, y_A)
plt.show()
```

But, this code is not work in line of y_A because n_A is tuple and len(A) is int, so this cannot be calculated.
Also, I think the line of n_A is not right.

How can I solve this problem.

I'm attaching the matlab code in this part which runs well.

```
edge_A = 0:max(A)/1000:max(A);
x_A = 0.5*max(A)/1000:max(A)/1000:max(A);
n_A = hiscounts(A, edge_A)
y_A = 1 - cumsum(n_A/length(A));
plot(x_A, y_A);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that np.histogram returns two values as a tuple:

```
Returns
-------
hist : array
    The values of the histogram. See `density` and `weights` for a
    description of the possible semantics.
bin_edges : array of dtype float
    Return the bin edges ``(length(hist)+1)``.
```

This seems to work:

```
A = np.random.rand(100000)
edge_A = np.linspace(0, max(A), 1000)
x_A = np.linspace(0.5*max(A)/1000, max(A), 1000)
(n_A, _) = np.histogram(A, bins=edge_A,)
y_A = 1 - np.cumsum(n_A / len(A), axis=0)
plt.figure()
plt.plot(x_A[1:], y_A)
plt.show()
```

It is easier to just use matplotlib:

```
plt.hist(A, 1000, cumulative=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to plot the data, you can use matplotlib directly:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pylab as plt

a = np.random.normal(loc=0.0, scale=1.0, size=int(1e4))
plt.figure()
plt.hist(a)
plt.show()
```

[image]